# Finding syntax error in code [PHP/HTML]

Tags: php, html, syntax, syntax-error

I have some HTML/PHP code in Dreamweaver and for the life of me I cannot figure out the cause of this error. The error reads, "There is a syntax error on line 318. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error." Could someone help? And yes, I know I have terrible commenting practice and variable nomenclature. The code can also be found [here](http://pastebin.com/UdqfFKqX)

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/feeds.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/mysql.php';
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){ header("location:/"); }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
Design by Free CSS Templates
http://www.freecsstemplates.org
Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License

Name       : Vegetables  
Description: A two-column, fixed-width design with dark color scheme.
Version    : 1.0
Released   : 20110416

-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="/image/png" href="/resources/favicon.png">
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Website • Edit Information</title>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1><a href="/">My Website</a></h1>
        <a href="/">This is the best website ever</a>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end #header -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/forum">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/minutes">Minutes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/docs">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
</div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
            <h2 class="title"><a href="#">Edit Information</a></h2>
            <div style="clear: both;"><form action="/admin"><input type="submit" value='Back'/></form></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="entry">

            <SCRIPT language="javascript">
            function add() {
                x++;
                var foo = document.getElementById('my_div');
                foo.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML +"<input type='text' name='tg"+x+"' placeholder='name'><br />";
            }
            function addch() {
                y++;
                var foo = document.getElementById('my_other_div');
                foo.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML +"<input type='text' name='ch"+y+"' placeholder='name'><br />";
            }
            function addws() {
                z++;
                var foo = document.getElementById('my_other_other_div');
                foo.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML +"<input type='text' name='ws"+z+"' placeholder='workshop name and leaders' style='width: 98%;'><br />";
            }
            function detect(form) {
                if(form.checked) {
                    window.backUpHtml = document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML;   
                    document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = '';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = window.backUpHtml;
                    window.backUpHtml = '';
                }
            }
            </SCRIPT>

             <form name="form1" method="post" action="./"><font color="#FFFFFF">
             <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#00000" style="max-width: 560px;">
             <tr>
             <td width="10%">Name</td>
             <td width="90%"><?php echo "<input name='name' type='text' value='".stripslashes($_POST['name'])."' required='required'/>"; ?><input type="checkbox" onclick="detect(this)" name="isyac" id="isyac" value="yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['isyac'])) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> /><label for="isyac">YAC Meeting</label></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Description</td>
             <td width="90%"><?php echo '<textarea name="desc" rows="5" cols="60" style="resize: vertical;" required="required">'.stripslashes($_POST["desc"]).'</textarea>'; ?></td>
             </tr>
             <tbody id="con_div">
             <!-- START OF CON DIV -->
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Touchgroup Leaders</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <?php 

             $blah = 1;

             while(isset($_POST['tg'.$blah])) {
                 echo '<input type="text" name="tg'.$blah.'" value="'.stripslashes($_POST["tg".$blah]).'" /><br />';
                 $blah++;
             }
             $hoo = $blah - 1;
             echo "<script language='javascript'> var x = ".$hoo."; </script>";

             ?>
             <div id="my_div"></div>
             <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="add()">

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Chaplains</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <?php
              $blah = 1;

             while(isset($_POST['ch'.$blah])) {
                 echo '<input type="text" name="ch'.$blah.'" value="'.stripslashes($_POST["ch".$blah]).'" /><br />';
                 $blah++;
             }
             $hoo = $blah - 1;
             echo "<script language='javascript'> var y = ".$hoo."; </script>";

             ?>
             <div id="my_other_div"></div>
             <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addch()">

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Workshops</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <?php
              $blah = 1;

             while(isset($_POST['ws'.$blah])) {
                 echo '<input type="text" name="ws'.$blah.'" value="'.stripslashes($_POST["ws".$blah]).'" style="width: 98%;"/><br />';
                 $blah++;
             }
             $hoo = $blah - 1;
             echo "<script language='javascript'> var z = ".$hoo."; </script>";

             ?>
             <div id="my_other_other_div"></div>
             <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addws()">

             </td>
             </tr>
             </tbody>
             <!-- END OF CON DIV -->
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Registration Links</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <?php echo '<input type="text" name="YouthLink" value="'.stripslashes($_POST['YouthLink']).'"/>&nbsp;Youth Link<br />
             <input type="text" name="AdultLink" value="'.stripslashes($_POST['AdultLink']).'"/>&nbsp;Adult Link'; ?>

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Start Date</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <select name='startmonth'>
                <?php $idk = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"); 

                foreach ($idk as $bob):

                if($bob = $_POST['startmonth']) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$bob.'" selected="selected">'.$bob.'</option>';
                } else {
                    echo '<option value="'.$bob.'">'.$bob.'</option>';
                }

                endforeach;

                ?>
             </select>
             <select name="startday">
                <?php 

                $x = 1;
                while($x <= 31) {
                    if((int)$_POST['startday'] == $x) {
                        echo "<option value='".$x."' selected='selected'>".$x."</option>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
                    }
                    $x++;
                }

                ?>
             </select>
             <select name="startyear">
                <?php $date = getdate(); 
                for($x = 0;$x < 3;$x++) { 
                    $y = (int)$date['year']+$x;
                    if($y == $_POST['startyear']) {
                    echo "<option value='".$y."' selected='selected'>".$y."</option>";
                    } else {
                    echo "<option value='".$y."'>".$y."</option>"; 
                    }
                }
                ?>
             </select>

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">End Date</td>
             <td width="90%">

             <select name='endmonth'>
                <?php $idk = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"); 

                foreach ($idk as $bob):

                if($bob = $_POST['endmonth']) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$bob.'" selected="selected">'.$bob.'</option>';
                } else {
                    echo '<option value="'.$bob.'">'.$bob.'</option>';
                }

                endforeach;

                ?>
             </select>
             <select name="endday">
                <?php 

                $x = 1;
                while($x <= 31) {
                    if((int)$_POST['endday'] < $x) {
                        echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
                    } else if((int)$_POST['endday'] == $x) {
                        echo "<option value='".$x."' selected='selected'>".$x."</option>";
                    } else if((int)$_POST['endday'] > $x) {
                        echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
                    }
                    $x++;
                }

                ?>
             </select>
             <select name="endyear">
                <?php $date = getdate(); 
                for($x = 0;$x < 3;$x++) { 
                    $y = (int)$date['year']+$x;
                    if($y == $_POST['endyear']) {
                        echo "<option value='".$y."' selected='selected'>".$y."</option>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value='".$y."'>".$y."</option>"; 
                    } 
                }
                ?>
             </select>

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="10%" style="vertical-align:top;">Location</td>
             <td width="90%">

                <?php echo '<input type="text" name="location" value="'.stripslashes($_POST['location']).'" required="required"/>'; ?>

             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td width="90%"></td>
             <td width="10%">

                <input type="hidden" name="blah" value="blah"/>
                <input type="submit" name="woohoo" value="Save" align="right"/>

             </td>
             </table>
             </form>
                 <?php if(isset($_POST['isyac'])) {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.backUpHtml = document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML;   
                document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = '';</script>"; ?>
            }
            </div>

        </div>

<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #content -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/side.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end #sidebar -->
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- end #page -->
<div id="footer-menu">
    <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/forum">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/minutes">Minutes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/docs">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; <?php $date = getdate(); echo $date['year']; ?> My Website. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please point out which line is 318? It would help to not have to copy it into a text editor to find it.

Comment: Consider using the [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in the future when writing templates, to avoid exactly these kinds of problems.

Comment: Why are people down voting? He supplied a link to code. It took me 3 seconds to click the link and find line 318.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to redefine your months array. You can declare that once and reuse the array for your month loops. Same deal for any redundant declaration. In fact, things like that may better be handled by functions - but that's not really the question you had here.

Comment: Most likely it's just Dreamweaver not understanding your mix of php and HTML. Consider using other IDE (there's lots of free ones: eclipse, aptana, notepad++, etc..). Also consider separating logic from template.

P.S. this is extremely bad code, variable names like $blah and $hoo are totally inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from this bit of code:

```
             <?php if(isset($_POST['isyac'])) {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.backUpHtml = document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML;   
            document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = '';</script>"; ?>
        }
```

the closing brace `}` needs to be inside the php tags (before the `?>`)

Answer (score 2):

I just glanced over your code and I would say this is probably it:

```
 </form>
                 <?php if(isset($_POST['isyac'])) {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.backUpHtml = document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML;   
                document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = '';</script>"; ?>
            }
            </div>
```

Your end curly should be inside the ?>

```
</form>
                 <?php if(isset($_POST['isyac'])) {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.backUpHtml = document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML;   
                document.getElementById('con_div').innerHTML = '';</script>"; 
                 }
                 ?>
            </div>
```